# How can I describe actions in a story format?

Tags: description, story

I am trying to create a description/story about what someone will do, for example a description of a man baking a cake, because I need to create descriptions of actions as part of my work. I know that an action has three parts, **transformation**, **circumstance of transformation** and **means**, but I'm unsure what these elements actually mean themselves or how to use them.

I want to be able to describe actions performed by something or someone, just like a story would be told, but I don't know how.

Comment: If you're talking about "user stories" or any other kind of technical writing like user manuals, etc., they follow slightly different rules of writing and you will get different answers.

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 4):

Forget the formality; that is a generalization of all action that can happen.

*"He broke three eggs into a large bowl."*

That is an action. The **transformation** is from eggs in their shell to just the eggs without their shell. The **means** is implied; it was his hands; we all know how to break eggs into a bowl. The **circumstances** are also implied (other than the bowl we specified); our natural expectation is that this is in a kitchen, preparing some sort of food.

*"With a whisk, he beat the eggs until they were a uniform light yellow liquid."*

More simply, just write the action somebody is taking with enough supporting detail for a typical reader to form a mental picture of it: **What**, **Where**, and **How**. Sometimes, **Why**. (In some writing, we want the **Why** to be a mystery for a later surprise reveal; so we describe a character doing mysterious tasks that in the end all culminate in a surprise "Why" was she doing those things. But we do get the **Why** eventually.)

Sometimes, for very common actions, some of these are implied and can be omitted.

*"He texted Lindsey."*

We are all familiar with how we text somebody (with a phone) and what that means, in the context of a scene, the **Where** and **How** and **Why** can all be implied. Just the **What** will suffice.

In your writing, just be sure these elements are clear to the reader. In the case of **Why**, at least eventually clear to the reader.

Comment: Thank you, this helps! But what is the difference between the circumstances and the means?

Comment: @RichardBamford I'm not sure. I would say the circumstances is the "situation", perhaps what prompts action, perhaps the environment. The means is any tools you use to accomplish the action. A knife, a whisk, a mixer, an oven.

Comment: @RichardBamford The means is any tools you use to accomplish the action. A knife, a whisk, a mixer, an oven. More examples: Perhaps a fist or kick. Again, the means may be implied: She baked the cake for one hour (an oven is implied). She knocked him out with a blow to the temple (her fist is implied). She kicked him in the wrist and his knife went flying (her foot is implied).

Comment: Sometimes you need to be sure you have sufficient context to successfully imply something.  My instinctive image of "calling Lindsey" was shouting to the other room.  So the following remark about phones was jarring.

Comment: @Jedediah Fair enough, I changed it from "called" to "texted".

Comment: This might not be true if the OP needs to some some kind of specific technical writing, though, like user manuals...since the OP says they need to do this for work.

Comment: @user3067860 The tags on the question say "description" and "story". Presumably they are not talking about technical writing.

Comment: @Amadeus Given the user's profile and confusion over how to write a story, I think the OP may need to write "user stories" which are not exactly stories in the traditional literary sense.

Comment: @user3067860 yes this is for technical writing, i need to be able to describe the actions performed in a situation e.g. the operations of an office.